# Sending A Text Value To PHP Using JQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I can't figure this out. I have this HTML

```
<input type="text" class="studno"><input type="button" value="Check" class="chstudno">
```

How can I send this to PHP using JQuery/AJAX? I have this code but I think it's wrong

```
var boom = 'booming';

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".chstudno").click(function(){
$(".inup").html(boom);
studnoch();
});
});

function studnoch(){
var studno = $('.studno').val();
$.post("prochat.php", {studno: studno};
}
```

As for the php file, it's a simple command that will check if the input variable matches any thing on the database.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant:

```
$(".studno").click(function(){
```

Or:

```
$(".chstudno").click(function(){
```

Instead of:

```
$(".check").click(function(){
```

`check` is the **value** not the class:

```
<input type="button" value="Check" class="chstudno">
```

Comment: @Miles. I can't guess you know, can you tell us what is not working? EXACTLY.

Answer (score 0):

Start off with a basic test: add a success function:

```
function studnoch() {
  var studno = $('.studno').val();
  alert('studnoch() has been called with studno=' + studno);
  $.post("prochat.php", {studno: studno}, 
    function(data, txt, xhqr) { alert('Ok, it worked'); }
  );
}
```

This should help you find out where you're going wrong...

BTW, it's probably a better idea to use an `id` for the input you want. This should make it unique:

```
<input type="text" class="studno" id="myinput">
```

Then retrieve it's value with:

```
$('#myinput').val();
```