# AJAX to PHP Sending A Value

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
var studno = $('#studno').val();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.go').click(function () {
        $('.inup').load('prochat.php', {
            studno: studno
        });
    });
});
```

I have this code and it's supposed to send the value of studno into prochat.php but everytime it does it only says undefined. Can anyone explain?

Comment: add `alert(studno)` before `$('.inup').load('prochat.php', studno:studno});`, what value is in the alert?

Comment: Is it just me, or it's almost like [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11175586/601179) ?

Comment: you are basically reading the value once, when the script loads, that's why there is no #studno element yet, so you keep getting undefined..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.go').click(function(){
        var studno = $('#studno').val();
        $('.inup').load('prochat.php', {studno:studno});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.go').click(function(){
        var studno = $('#studno').val();
        $('.inup').load('prochat.php', {studno:studno});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll just accept it when after 11 minutes (cause that's what stack overflow says. lol)

Comment: This will always pass the same value though

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Turns out this works

```
$('.inup').load('prochat.php', {studno: $('#studno').val()});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work better:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.go').click(function () {
        $('.inup').load('prochat.php', {
            studno: $('#studno').val()
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These could be possible reasons:

1. at the line where you are assigning the value to studno, the value of studno might be undefined
2. #studno is not defined in the html

possible solutions:

-. try assigning the value within the click function:

like this:

```
$('.go').click(function(){
    studno = $('#studno').val();
    $('.inup').load('prochat.php', {studno:studno});
});
```

-. make sure that the element with id studno exists in the html document